# Login into a website using wget

Tags: curl, wget

I can download a file through a  URL if I am logged into the website.

https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary%2CAllCampaignsChart%2CAllAds%2CAllCampaignsSites&start_date=9-25-2016&end_date=10-9-2016&format=xlsx&currency=USD

Now, if I try to access that link using `wget`, it gives me 500 since it does not see me as a logged in user through wget.

I have tried logging in

```
wget --save-cookies addrollCookied.txt --post-data 'user=userName&password=password' https://app.adroll.com/account/account/signin
```

And infact tried to load this cookies file while hitting the URL I want to, but `wget` request is just not treated as a loggedin user.

```
wget --load-cookies addrollCookied.txt -p  'https://app.adroll.com/api/v1/export/all_campaigns_report?advertisable=T4ZPAGYESJEZZMCCBVEMHK&reports=AllCampaignsSummary,AllCampaignsChart,AllAds,AllCampaignsSites&format=csv&currency=USD' --debug
```

Answer (score 0):

The authentication parameters for wget are

```
--user=USERNAME
--password=PASSWORD
```

You might need to set

```
--auth-no-challenge
```

as well.

Comment: Your example above is for basic authenticion where the OP appears to be trying to get forms based authention to work..